# serf failing, sending https request to port 80 instead of 443, why?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

When requesting via https it looks like serf is funnelling the request via port 80 instead of 443?

```
[Mon Jan 16 10:25:48.007386 2017] [error] [pid 350] [mod_pagespeed 1.11.33.4-0 @350] Serf status 120171(APR does not understand this error code) polling for 1 threaded fetches for 0.05 seconds
[Mon Jan 16 10:25:48.007539 2017] [error] [pid 350] [mod_pagespeed 1.11.33.4-0 @350] Serf status 120171(APR does not understand this error code) polling for 1 threaded fetches for 0.05 seconds
[Mon Jan 16 10:25:53.021234 2017] [warn] [pid 350] [mod_pagespeed 1.11.33.4-0 @350] Fetch timed out: https://www.domain.com/assets/76dc6ad2/style.min.css (connecting to:10.33.12.222:80) (1) waiting for 50 ms
```

SSL termination on the load balancer. SSL is also configured to work from behind the load balancer as well so https can be served from within the network.

```
ModPagespeedFetchHttps enable
ModPagespeedRespectXForwardedProto on
ModPagespeedEnableFilters prioritize_critical_css
```

How to have serf request https via port 443?

Comment: I can successfully request the https file via wget while logged into the web server.
```$ wget https://www.domain.com/assets/76dc6ad2/style.min.css
Success!``` However, serf can't get it.

Comment: I am curious about this question too. There isnt much info on serf. We are running into this error behind Cloudflare. When using strict SSL apparently they don't send the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, so I don't think Pagespeed understands this is a secure request. Also, as a note, in newer versions of Pagespeed `ModPagespeedFetchHttps` is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

@dhaupin 
I don't seem to notice that error anymore.

This is probably what fixed it, explicitly handling https requests.

```
ModPagespeedLoadFromFile "https://example.com" "/var/www/example/"
ModPagespeedRespectXForwardedProto on
```

Comment: Setting `ModPagespeedLoadFromFile` helped slightly (note, do it for each domain line by line). The error is still here on my end, but its kinda crazy: serf only fails for 2 files, an .svg and a .cur. Setting `ModPagespeedDisallow` for those file types buttons up the rest.